# Android app publishing checklist

Tags: android, android-logcat, publishing, android-log

The android app publishing checklist says that I need to delete all Log statements from my code. Does that mean I need to delete them or would just commenting them out do? I would need those Log statements for updation and maintenance purpose later on so i don't want to delete them.[Publishing checklist](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to remove your logs from code, just disable them in `RELEASE` mode. The easiest way to achieve that, check mode before log something

```
 if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Log.i("TAG", "Log");
 }
```

But it will be painful if you have a lot of logs in your code, so good idea is to write your custom wrapper above the Android `Log` class, with ability to turn on/off logging in one place, for example in `Application` class.

Or you can use some smart loggers like [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber)

**EDIT**

About log wrapper, to be honest I've never created such wrapper, I prefer to use Timber, but the simplest version may look like this

```
public class Logger {

    public static void e(String tag, String body) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.e(tag, body);
        }
    }

    public static void v(String tag, String body) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.v(tag, body);
        }

    }

    ...
}
```

and instead of using

```
Log.e("Tag", "Body");
```

use

```
Logger.e("Tag", "Body");
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the custom wrapper solution please.?

Comment: I commented my Log statements because rewriting them using a custom wrapper would have been a pain.

Comment: @user2197909 if having logs in your code is not critical you can of course remove them, but I will be much convenient to use wrapper in the future, because you will always have logs when debug your app.

Answer (score 0):

The publishing check list just don't want you to include log statements when your app is published because it may contain some sensitive information and that sort of stuff. So you just need to make sure that it is not executed.

**As long as the log statement is not executed, it's fine.**

You can do the following:

- Delete the statement
- comment the statement
- add an impossible if statement:

```
    if (0 != 0) {
       //log
    }
```

P.S. The second solution the the most recommended.